# How best to set up a schema in DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Is it best to have one giant table by say UserId and store everything with it in DynamoDB or create a super denormalized schema with lots of tables?

Lets suppose I have a Image sharing site like Flickr. I would want to have:

```
users (userId, email, passwords, names)
images (imageId, userId, filename, size)
comments (commentId, userId, imageId, textOfComment)
```

This above is a very normalized way of doing things (that I understand) and would be 3 tables. I would query them based on what I needed.

Say if I had a userId and wanted to get all of their images:

```
query = select * from images where userId = @userId
```

But DynamoDB doesn't seem to work this way as it partions the data by the keys:

userId, imageId, commentsId would be the keys and partion the tables

How would I get all the images by a particular user? Do I just have one big table (which seems sooooooo wrong)? Or should I have the imageId's as a set in the users table (that could get large if say one user had 1,000,000 images)? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think this can work quite well. A general rule of thumb for DynamoDB (or NoSQL in general) is: storage = cheap and CPU = expensive (this is also reflected in the pricing).

You can duplicate data: in the comments you not only specify the image_id, but also all image properties, for example. This is cheaper and more efficient than 2 queries (provided there are not hundreds of 'columns').

Your query could work, just set up your indices correctly (set a global secondary index on images with userId as hash and imageId as range, then you can query on userId alone using that index).